# C# Regex syntax for pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I need to make sure a field has the proper syntax using Regex in `C#`, before proceeding. Here is my code:

```
Description = 'AB1234567,AB3456789;AB2345678';

Regex reg = new Regex("(AB.{7},?)*;?(AB.{7},?)*");
Match match = reg.Match(Description);
if (!match.Success)
{
    //code to raise error
}
```

So, some syntax rules:

- The field has elements of 2 letters (in this case AB) followed by 7 characters.
- These elements are comma separated, either on the left or right side of a ";". Which side they are in indicating their properties, but either side can be empty.
- If the right side is not empty then ";" is mandatory, if empty it is optional.
- The last element of each side cannot end with a ",".

**Correct examples:**

```
 - AB1234567,AB3456789;AB2345678
 - AB1234567,AB3456789;
 - AB1234567
 - ;AB2345678,AB34567890
```

**Wrong examples:**

```
 - AB1234567,;AB2345678
 - AB3456789;AB2345678,
```

My regular expression is not complete, but I cannot come up with how to consider all cases. What is the correct regular expression for this problem?

Comment: what is the end goal? do yuo need to extract the AB***  in list or something?

Comment: Yes, into two lists.

Comment: Ok,   here the regex should work           (?<ABGroup>AB\d{7}[,;])        you will receive match as a named group.  goto: https://regex101.com/    put yuor regex expression and test data....you will do that fine..

Comment: Okay, for downvoting do it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Straight answer and much more simplified version, Should work in all options.

```
    bool  IsValid(string line)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) return true;
        return !line.Trim().EndsWith(",");
    }
```

---

```
    IEnumerable<string> GetTokens(string line)
    {
        var pattern = @"(AB\d{7}([,;]|[^0-9a-zA-Z]|$))";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            yield return match.Value;
        }
    }
```

---

```
    string inputLine = ";AB2345678,AB34567890";

    string[] leftRight = inputLine.Split(new[] { ';' });
    string left =string.Empty, right = string.Empty;

    if (leftRight.Length > 0) left = leftRight[0];
    if (leftRight.Length > 1) right = leftRight[1];

    bool isLeftValid = IsValid(left);
    bool isRightValid = IsValid(right);

    IEnumerable<string> leftTokens = null, rightTokens = null;

    if (isLeftValid) leftTokens = GetTokens(left);
    if (isRightValid) rightTokens = GetTokens(right);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your expression is almost correct, you just need to ensure that a comma is followed by another `AB` group. You can do that with a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), like this:

```
^(AB.{7}(,(?=AB))?)*;?(AB.{7}(,(?=AB))?)*$
```

You also need to put in the start and end markers otherwise you will get multiple submatches.

This expression will not match the `;AB2345678,AB34567890` sample because it has 8 digits in the last group instead of 7

Edit: If you want the AB groups in a nice collection, try

```
^((?<left>AB.{7})(,(?=AB))?)*;?((?<right>AB.{7})(,(?=AB))?)*$
```

Then `match.Groups["left"]?.Captures` and `match.Groups["right"]?.Captures` will give you the respective matched strings (or null). This is called a named capture.

Comment: Downvoters care to explain? The given expressions work correctly for all samples (except the one I mentioned that doesn't fit the description). You can check it out here: http://regexstorm.net/tester